# Вывод cp-1251 из БД на странице utf-8 средствами Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, codeigniter, cp1251

Есть БД MYSQL в кодировке cp-1251.
Есть страницы, которые надо выводить в utf-8.
Что нужно указать в настройках Codeigniter, чтобы данные из базы выводились нормально?
Прописывал в autoload/config/database.php параметры $db['default']['char_set'] и $db['default']['db_collat'] в utf8 и cp1251 в разных вариациях - разницы никакой почему-то.

Comment: прописывать надо utf8. а не получается скорее всего потому что в базе не 1251, а какой-нибудь винегрет

Comment: @Ипатьев там в самом деле винегрет, половина таблиц cp-1251, половина utf-8. Была идея сделать через 2 обьекта баз данных - каждый на свою кодировку.

Comment: надо перекодировать все в одну